# Не работает ApiController после публикации в IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, http, mvc

Создал проект web application MVC, в него ещё добавил ApiController. Всего у меня 2 контроллера - 1-н обычный Controller (загрузка главной стр.) и 1-н ApiController. В VS проект запускается на IIS Express и оба контроллера работают норм.

Опубликовал проект в IIS (скопировал файлы в созданную папку в inetpub из D:\My_PROGRAMS\UploadInmeta\AploadPaymentsAccruals\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp после публикации в VS) и работает только 1-н контроллер - обычный (Controller), а ApiController работать перестал - при вызове открывает новую страницу и пишет "Сайт localhost не позволяет установить соединение".

Подскажите в чем дело? Как исправить?

Пробовал добавлять порт (6141), который VS выделяла для ApiController в исключения) - не помогло.

Контроллеры:

```
public class FileApiController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/FileApi/UploadFile")]
        public void UploadFile()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var fileName in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys)
                    {
                        HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[fileName];
                        if (file != null)
                        {
                            FileDTO fileDTO = new FileDTO();
 
                            fileDTO.FileActualName = file.FileName;
                            fileDTO.FileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                            fileDTO.ContentType = file.ContentType;
 
                            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
                            string fileUniqueNameExt = file.FileName.Replace(".", " " + dateTime.ToString().Replace('.', '_').Replace(':', '_') + ".");
                            fileDTO.FileUniqueName = fileUniqueNameExt.Substring(0, fileUniqueNameExt.LastIndexOf('.'));
 
                            var rootPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles");
 
                            var fileSavePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(rootPath, fileDTO.FileUniqueName + fileDTO.FileExt);
 
                            file.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
 
                            FileModel.SaveFileInDB(fileDTO);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<h3>" + ex.ToString() + "</h3>");
                }
            }
            var infoFile = HttpContext.Current.Request["infoFile"];
        }
 
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/FileApi/DownloadFile")]
        public Object DownloadFile(String uniqueName)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 
            //Physical Path of Root Folder
            var rootPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles");
 
            //Find File from DB against unique name
            var fileDTO = FileModel.GetFileByUniqueID(uniqueName);
 
            if (fileDTO != null)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                var fileFullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(rootPath, fileDTO.FileUniqueName + fileDTO.FileExt);
 
                byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileFullPath);
                System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(file);
 
                response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(file);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                 
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(fileDTO.ContentType);// obj.DocumentName.Substring(obj.DocumentName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1, 3);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileDTO.FileActualName;
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                return response;
            }
        }
 
    }
 
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //Physical Path of Root Folder
            string rootPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles");
            //
            //var files = FileModel.GetAllFiles();
            List<FileDTO> files = FileModel.GetFilesInPath(rootPath);
            return View(files);
        }
    }
```

Главная страница, с которой осуществляются все запросы:

```
@model List<AploadPaymentsAccruals.Models.FileDTO>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Main page";
}
 
<div>
    <br />
    Данные о файле: <input type="text" id="infoFile" /><br />
    <input type="file" id="uploadFile" /><br />
    <input type="button" id="btnUpload" value="Upload" onclick="RequestUpload()"/>
</div>
 
<div>
    <div id="container">
        <ul>
            @foreach (var fileObj in Model)
            {
                <li><span>@fileObj.FileActualName </span><a href="#" uname="@fileObj.FileUniqueName" class="download">Скачать файл с сервера</a> / <a href="#" uname="@fileObj.FileUniqueName" class="remove">Удалить файл с сервера</a></li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
 
@section scripts{
 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".download").click(function () {
                var unqiuename = $(this).attr('uname');
                var url = "http://localhost:6141/api/FileApi/DownloadFile?uniqueName=" + unqiuename
                window.open(url);
            });            
 
            $(".remove").click(function () {
                var unqiuename = $(this).attr('uname');
                var url = "http://localhost:6141/api/FileApi/RemoveFile?uniqueName=" + unqiuename
                window.open(url);
            });
           });
 
        function RequestUpload(){
            var data = new FormData();
            var files = $("#uploadFile").get(0).files;
            // Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection
            if (files.length > 0) {
                data.append("UploadedFile", files[0]);
            }
            data.append("infoFile", $("#infoFile").val());  //Other data
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:6141/api/FileApi/UploadFile",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('File uploaded');
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (result, status, er) {
                    alert("error: " + result + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
                }
            });
        } 
    </script>
}
```

При деплои напрямую на сам сервер почему-то выдает ошибку

> Не удалось выполнить задачу Web Deploy. (Сайт "uploadinmeta" не
> существует.  Дополнительные сведения:
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST.)    AploadPaymentsAccruals      0

Поэтому копирую раздеплоеные файлы в IIS в ручную.

Настройки публикации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Из ajax уберите localhost и порт. Просто указывайте путь к метод контроллера.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, Если прописываю url: "http://api/FileApi/UploadFile", то он мне выдает ошибку - "api/FileApi/UploadFile:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, может это из-за той ошибки которая выдается при попытке опубликовать прямо в IIS (добавил описание в вопрос)

Comment: Решение оказалось такое - нужно после localhost:80 ещё указать имя сайта, которое указывается при публикации, а потом уже путь к контроллеру

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы публиковали проект в IIS - вы назначили ему какой-то хост, порт и виртуальный адрес, потому что это свойства хоста, а не проекта. Если вы просто копировали файлы в inetpub - скорее всего, это `http://0.0.0.0:80/`. Именно по этому адресу вы и должны направлять запрос (только замените 0.0.0.0 на IP-адрес или доменное имя своего компьютера). Ну или используйте относительный путь, если страница хостится там же

Comment: Если прописываю "url: "http://localhost:80/api/FileApi/UploadFile", то выдает ошибку - "jquery?v=8Oos0avDZyP…DGSe3sRQdCSYrgEQ1:1 POST http://localhost/api/FileApi/UploadFile 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery?v=8Oos0avDZyP…DGSe3sRQdCSYrgEQ1:1
ajax @ jquery?v=8Oos0avDZyP…DGSe3sRQdCSYrgEQ1:1
RequestUpload @ uploadinmeta:111
onclick @ VM37 uploadinmeta:38

Comment: может это происходит из-за ошибки, которая возникает при попытке опубликовать прямо в IIS (добавил описание в вопрос)

Comment: Решение оказалось такое - нужно после http://0.0.0.0:80/ ещё указать имя сайта, которое указывается при публикации, а потом уже путь к контроллеру